# Laragon MySQL ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061 "Unknown Error")

Tags: mysql, laragon

I'm using http://laragon.org for my server

I got a problem yesterday my apps cannot connect to mysql and give me this error message

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'
>   (10061 "Unknown Error").

and I tried to run `mysql -v` but got same error. I'm using :

- OS Windows 10 64bit
- Laragon v0.7
- No antivirus running
- No others server running (this is the only server in the pc)

I'm searching everywhere but the answer is to start MySQL service, but I don't find any MySQL service in `services.msc` (I read on their site if Laragon won't add anything to the System Path Variable.
But, you are freely to use `composer`, `artisan`, `mysql`, `mysqldump`, `httpd`, `redis-cli`, ... in Laragon' shell)

> [image: error message]

and in their control panel status MySQL 10.0.20 started.. i tried to restart all service and pc but still got the problem

anyone know how to fix this problem ?

UPDATE : `mysql -V` is working, just need to uppercase -v, but still cannot connect to my MySQL Database

Comment: I *think* this happens when mysqld isn't listening on the specified address, but I have no idea how to fix it on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running a very old version of Laragon.
Try installing Laragon **0.9 151004**, I believe it helps.

Comment: actually i don't want to reinstall my laragon because I'm afraid of losing my database. Then i tried copy database from dir database folder to another machine and the result my database works.. so i choose to reinstall laragon and for now my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

From [the website](http://laragon.org/), it appears that:

> ### No Windows Services
>
> Laragon manage other servers by its own optimal service manager.

This provides a reason as to why you couldn't find MySQL service in `services.msc`. Can you check the interface itself (if you can not find the laragon service itself in `services.msc`) and check whether MySQL service is running or not?

> [image: laragon]

Additionally, look into laragon's installation directory for a `log`s file. Close and restart laragon if everything fails.